# Does one 'have' or does one 'hold' a fascination?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I know that a fascination 'holds' the individual, but how does one phrase the act of being fascinated? i.e.; does one 'hold' or does one 'have' a fascination?

Would it be more appropriate to say that he or she is 'held' by a fascination?

Comment: Is there a way that you can say that sentence more specifically how you are trying to use it? (ie. "She was held by a fascination of the otters, and wouldn't leave the zoo.")

Comment: @BillyNair "In those days I held - and still hold – a fascination with [...]" vs "In those days I had – and still have – a fascination with [...]"

Comment: Do you, @bradleygriffith, take this fascination, to have and to hold, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I (native U.S. speaker) would use *is fascinated with* or *is fascinated by*.

> As a child, I *was fascinated with* with any kind of button I could press.  While these days I *am fascinated by* touch-screen technology, I miss the satisfying click of a button.

If forced to use *have* or *held* I could use either depending on which is the subject and which is the object:

> Vampire romances *hold no fascination* for me. I *have no fascination* with the undead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *held* is more appropriate.

> He is held by a fascination of sailing in the sea.